# SignalR not updated frequently

Tags: azure, .net-core, signalr, azure-webjobs

I have a azure web job and I update the status of web job running by reaching the steps

Considering the status Web job started, Getting the details, Success, signalR display the Web job started and Success only and skips the  Getting the details status. SignalR skips the status like this randomly

Note: I have write a common method for update all status

Comment: Can you please share the code you are using? It's difficult to diagnose exactly what is happening without knowing how you are connecting to SignalR. Also, are you running your own hub or using Azure SignalR service?

Comment: We found the root cause it is because of the azure configuration's instance count. So we are planning to use azure signalrR service.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-3.1#scaleout-differences 
 
Based on the above blog and  our application is in Asp.NET not Asp.NET Core. Can you please share on your thoughts for azure signalR service in ASP .NET.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. The service will work with .NET Framework, but there are some features that are incompatible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-dotnet